# how to implement stack of divs not overlapping?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I use Zurb's Foundation Framework to build a website and my issue is that the footer is overlapping the content area.

My HTML Structure:

```
- Header
- Site-Wrapper 
  + Site-Canvas
    * Site-Menu
    * row (content)
- Footer
```

The full website can be seen on:
https://fadendaten.herokuapp.com/t/categories/clothing

How can i manage to have the Footer not overlapping the other divs?
I tried to repositioning the Footer on the same level of the content row but the Footer still overlaps the content div.

Comment: Add some clearfixes first, because the body doesn't have full page height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
.shelf .products {
    height: 330px;
}
```

or override it with `height: auto;`

By restricting those wrappers to 330px height while having more products in them, the excess products will overlap the footer due to overflowing.